# How to create DevExtreme Multi-Level Headers using a recursive Vue loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, devextreme

I'm using DevExtreme components for my Vue3 app. Based on this sample ( [docs](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MultiRowHeadersBands/Vue/Light/) / [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/cqfik) ) I want to create multi level headers based on a configuration. I think I will have to use a recursive loop for that.

First I created a component **GridColumn** acting as a node in a tree which is able to render itself with or without its nested children

```
<template>
  <!-- If there are no children use the data-field prop -->
  <dx-column
    v-if="gridColumn.children === undefined"
    :caption="gridColumn.caption"
    :data-field="gridColumn.dataField"
  />
  <!-- If there are children nest them inside -->
  <dx-column v-else :caption="gridColumn.caption">
    <grid-column
      v-for="childGridColumn in gridColumn.children"
      :key="childGridColumn.caption"
      :gridColumn="childGridColumn"
    />
  </dx-column>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { DxColumn } from "devextreme-vue/data-grid";
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "grid-column",
  components: {
    "dx-column": DxColumn,
  },
  props: {
    gridColumn: Object,
  },
});
</script>
```

Now I can use this component inside the **Home** view

```
<template>
  <dx-data-grid :data-source="data" :show-borders="true">
    <grid-column
      v-for="columnDefinition in columnDefinitions"
      :key="columnDefinition.caption"
      :gridColumn="columnDefinition"
    />
  </dx-data-grid>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import DxDataGrid from "devextreme-vue/data-grid";
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

import GridColumn from "../components/GridColumn.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    "dx-data-grid": DxDataGrid,
    "grid-column": GridColumn,
  },
  setup() {
    const columnDefinitions = ref([
      {
        caption: "Col 1",
        dataField: "fieldOne",
      },
      {
        caption: "Col 2",
        children: [
          {
            caption: "Col 2.1",
            dataField: "fieldTwo",
          },
          {
            caption: "Col 2.2",
            dataField: "fieldThree",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        caption: "Col 3",
        children: [
          {
            caption: "We need to go deeper",
            children: [
              {
                caption: "... deeper ...",
                children: [
                  {
                    caption: "... almost ...",
                    children: [
                      {
                        caption: "GO FOR IT",
                        dataField: "fieldFour",
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);

    const data = ref([
      {
        fieldOne: "foo",
        fieldTwo: 2,
        fieldThree: new Date(),
        fieldFour: { x: "y" },
      },
      {
        fieldOne: "some more text",
        fieldTwo: 123,
        fieldThree: new Date(),
        fieldFour: { a: "b" },
      },
    ]);

    return { columnDefinitions, data };
  },
});
</script>
```

The rendered result will be

[image]

which is not what I wanted, the captions are wrong and the parent headers are missing. You can checkout a [sandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/devextreme-vue-recursive-grid-wlxd6)

Just to show what I want to achieve

[image]

with a working [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-level-headers-bands-devextreme-data-grid-forked-t27p6)

Does someone know how what is wrong with my implementation? And maybe there are even simpler solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for the recursive element, but you can use the `columns` property on the data-table itself.

Your data-table would look like this

```html
<dx-data-grid 
  :data-source="data" 
  :show-borders="true"
  :columns="columnDefinitions">
</dx-data-grid>
```

Now you only have to rename the `children` array to `columns`.

```js
const columnDefinitions = ref([
  {
    caption: "Col 1",
    dataField: "fieldOne",
  },
  {
    caption: "Col 2",
    columns: [
      {
        caption: "Col 2.1",
        dataField: "fieldTwo",
      },
      {
        caption: "Col 2.2",
        dataField: "fieldThree",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    caption: "Col 3",
    columns: [
      {
        caption: "We need to go deeper",
        columns: [
          {
            caption: "... deeper ...",
            columns: [
              {
                caption: "... almost ...",
                columns: [
                  {
                    caption: "GO FOR IT",
                    dataField: "fieldFour",
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

The only documentation mentioning a `columns` property I could find was [here](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/). It's not very explicit on how to use that with vue though.